# storing data in databases in android

Tags: android

i am having a program in which i am having 4 edittext name,age,contact,email. I am having 2 buttons save and view.I want a program of how to save values.
I will be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). Ideal way is to use Shared Preferences => asociative array